# Geometry nodes point distribute

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I wanted to create a grass field, and when i added point distribute the grass falled down.Please help me.
geometry nodes:
[image]

Comment: i would first recommend using a newer blender version...

Comment: What version of blender are you using? Aside from your current problem, blender's geometry nodes have changed in the most recent version(s). I would recommend learning the "new way" first, to save yourself troubles down the line (Version 3.1+).

Comment: You probably made it in 2.93 following some tutorial, updated to 3.0, and had a total failure, which will be even bigger (actually the attribute comes back in business) in 3.2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using an outdated version `2.93` geometry nodes setup.

The updated correct setup is:

[image]